# The lower bound for the series $\sum_{k = 1}^{\infty} \frac{k (1 - \theta)^k}{k! \log^3 (c + k)}$.

Tags: sequences-and-series, inequality, summation, upper-lower-bounds

Suppose $0 < \theta < 1$ and $c$ is a positive constant no more than 3. I want to find a sharp lower bound for the series
$$\sum_{k = 1}^{\infty} \frac{k (1 - \theta)^k}{k! \log^3 (c + k)}.$$
Since the denominator contains the log function, I don't know how to deal with it.

Does anyone know the solution? Thanks so much!

Comment: Not sure, I understood the question correctly. If $\theta \rightarrow 1$, the value of the series $\rightarrow 0$, so the lower bound is 0, is that what you are asking?

Comment: @D.Dmitriy Thanks. 0 is a lower bound for this series. But I really want is an explicit function of $\theta$ and $c$.

Comment: Lower bound is defined over a set of values. If you set both $\theta$ and $c$, then the series just evaluates to some number. What kind of lower bound do you mean?

Comment: @D.Dmitriy $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{k(1-\theta)^{k}}{k ! \log ^{3}(c+k)} \geq f(\theta, c)$, where $f(\theta, c)$ has an explicit expression.

Comment: I think your question is ill-posed. $f(\theta, c) = 0$ is an example of such function with explicit expression. If you are asking for the sharp lower bound, for each $\theta$, $c$, then, well, lower bound for a value is the value itself. Here it will be $f(\theta, c) = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{k(1-\theta)^{k}}{k ! \log ^{3}(c+k)}$.

Comment: @D.Dmitriy Yeah. Maybe you are right. The most correct answer is exactly zero.

Comment: For example, we have $\frac{k}{\log^3(c+k)} \ge \frac{k}{\log^3(3+k)}
\ge \frac{1}{\log^3 4}$ for all $k\ge 1$.
Then a lower bound is
$\frac{1}{\log^3 4} \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{(1-\theta)^k}{k!} = 
\frac{1}{\log^3 4} (\mathrm{e}^{1-\theta} -1)$. Am I right?

Comment: @RiverLi Thanks so much. I can handle the relative problem more conveniently with your answer.

Comment: @香结丁 You may try to find better simple lower bounds.